# Is it possible to draw a JLabel without calling add() or creating an image of it?

Tags: java, performance, swing, jlabel

To be specific, I want to draw the contents of a JLabel onto a Graphics object.
**I do not want to add the label to any frame or panel! Please check the comments for further explanations.**

After some research, I found a method to do it. For example, I have a label that I draw to x = 100, y = 100.

```
public void drawIt(Graphics graphics)
{
    Dimension size = label.getPreferredSize();
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Graphics imageGraphics = image.createGraphics();
    label.paint(imageGraphics);
    graphics.drawImage(image, 100, 100, null);

    imageGraphics.dispose();
}
```

This works fine, but there is a major backdraft: 
When I call this in a paint method (in any JFrame or JPanel or the like), it is terribly slow and uses a lot of memory. Afaik, it is to be generally avoided to allocate (image) objects in the paint methods.

Calling

```
label.paint(graphics);
```

works fine and fast, but calling this method always draws the label at the coordinate 0,0 which  I cannot influence by setLocation et cetera.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to draw a JLabel instead of drawing styled text?

Comment: `Please accept and do not discuss this.` -- ??? please at least provide some justification for this unusual request. Please avoid putting stipulations on free advice given by volunteers.

Comment: @abmitchell
I want to write a lot of texts via drawString in a specific rectangle. The text needs to wrap after its width is greater than the rectangles width. It should try to wrap words after spaces and also break words that are too long for the rectangle. However, what I wanted was to draw a String as if it was in a JLabel.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels
I want to wrap my code in a reusable class that I can share between several projects. For instance, in some project's paintComponent method of a JFrame I just want to call "WrappedTextDrawer.draw(graphics, longText, x, y, width, height)" and do not want to meddle around with adding tons of JLabels.

Comment: Why not use a JTextComponent as they have facilities for word wrap. For example JTextArea, JEditorPane or JTextPane? You can change their appearance so that they look more label like if desired. I strongly sense that your main question is actually an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), that you may be barking up the wrong tree, and that if you give us more of the details of your problem space (not the code solution), we may be able to give you a better, cleaner, more adaptable solution.

Comment: @Above have you considered using a custom JTextArea? You can modify it to look like a JLabel, and it has wrapping functionality. If you want to implement a custom class that will draw wrapped text with a `Graphics` object, you should implement the logic and math to do that and write a `String`, not a `JLabel`

Comment: @abmitchell: great minds think alike.

Comment: Reading my question again, I can clearly understand you, @Hovercraft. I guess, the real gist of the question is "How can I wrap and draw String just like in JLabels, JTextAreas etc.?"

It is true that I could implement the logic and write my own "draw wrapped text to Graphics object" method. I even tried to implement this function, but than I realized that the JLabel (or JTextArea etc.) classes already have this functionality. So I though: Maybe I do not need to reinvent the wheel :(

Comment: Again, why can't you not use JTextArea or JTextPane?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels
It's the same thing as with the JLabel I stated in my 2nd comment. I want to be able to draw the text onto a Graphics object rather than adding the JTextArea/Pane onto a frame/panel. My "wish" would be a class that is closed in itself, that does not depend on any frame/panel and is thus callable like "WrappedTextDrawer.draw(graphics, longText, x, y, width, height)" in any graphical context.

Comment: `I do not want to meddle with adding tons of ...` sounds to me like a case of (1) premature optimization allied with (2) something I will call "algorithmic fixation".  In other words, you have a "WAY YOU WANT TO DO IT", regardless of whether it is a good idea, regardless even of whether it will solve your original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a method to the achieve the results I wanted.

Since

```
label.paint(graphics);
```

takes no x and y parameters, and the other method (painting it to a new BufferedImage and paint this) is not very performant, it is possible to call Graphics#translate(x, y) to alter the Graphics object's origin.

E.g. to paint my label to 100, 100, this does the work:

```
graphics.translate(100, 100);
label.paint(graphics);
graphics.translate(-100, -100); //set origin back to 0, 0 for following calls
```

Of course this should work for every other Component.